# Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required - Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

Trying to `precompile` my assets in Rails app and `sync` with `Amazon S3 Storage`:

with this mesage:

Any feedback appreciated:

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)
response => #<Excon::Response:0x00000007c45a98 @data={:body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required</Message><ArgumentValue>AWS [\"AKIAINSIQYCZLWYSROWQ\", \"7RAxhY5nLkbACICMqjDlee5pCaEhf4LKgSpJ+R9k\"]:LakbTXVMX6I72MViNie/fe+79qU=</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><RequestId>250C76936044E6D5</RequestId><HostId>j2jK/dv0xTnNddtSFHuVicGv5wWjXl4zXuhOyPcO6+2WWlAYWSkn0CHPwdtnOPet</HostId></Error>", :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"250C76936044E6D5", "x-amz-id-2"=>"j2jK/dv0xTnNddtSFHuVicGv5wWjXl4zXuhOyPcO6+2WWlAYWSkn0CHPwdtnOPet", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Tue, 20 Aug 2013 13:28:36 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>400, :remote_ip=>"205.251.235.165"}, @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required</Message><ArgumentValue>AWS [\"AKIAINSIQYCZLWYSROWQ\", \"7RAxhY5nLkbACICMqjDlee5pCaEhf4LKgSpJ+R9k\"]:LakbTXVMX6I72MViNie/fe+79qU=</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><RequestId>250C76936044E6D5</RequestId><HostId>j2jK/dv0xTnNddtSFHuVicGv5wWjXl4zXuhOyPcO6+2WWlAYWSkn0CHPwdtnOPet</HostId></Error>", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"250C76936044E6D5", "x-amz-id-2"=>"j2jK/dv0xTnNddtSFHuVicGv5wWjXl4zXuhOyPcO6+2WWlAYWSkn0CHPwdtnOPet", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Tue, 20 Aug 2013 13:28:36 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=400, @remote_ip="205.251.235.165">
```

Comment: Looks you're using fog - which version?

Comment: I am using gem "fog", "~> 1.15.0", uploading with carrierwave

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check where your setting the `aws_access_key_id` to use with your asset syncer.

This should be something that looks like `AKIAINSIQYCZLWYSROWQ`, whereas it looks like you've set it to a 2 element array of both your access key id and the secret access key.

Furthermore, given that you've now placed those credentials in the public domain you should revoke them immediately.

Comment: Great. And please do revoke those credentials or anyone could use them, potentially racking up significant cost

Answer (score 12):

Have had an error with the same message twice now and both times it was due to pasting an extra space at the end of access key or secret key in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Extra space at the end of access key is one issue and the reason is copying from Amazon IAM UI puts the extra space.

The other thing is that when you have configuration in /.aws/credentials folder or other configuration conflicts with environment values. This happened to me when configuring CircleCI and docker machines.

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens if you haven't enabled GET/POST in cloudfront and try to do GET/POST to api which are hosted behind cloudfront.

Answer (score -2):

Error 400 occurs more than 20 cases. Here is a pdf that describe all errors: [List of AWS S3 Error Codes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/s3-api.pdf)